# What does this notation mean "?:" in regex?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I found the below regex from RegexLib.

```
^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:
(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(\/|-|\.)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468]
[048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))
(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

It is from http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=113

I don't understand the notation "?:", which is used many times in this regex. It seems ":" is not in the [chartsheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx)

I am that familiar with regex. Could anyone show an example, with the regex and inputs?

Comment: It makes the sub pattern non-capturing

Comment: For some extra explanation check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/557306) question/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:)
```

stands for *non capturing group*. See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) ([perl](/questions/tagged/perl) is IMHO the most advanced language to play with REGEX : [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) by example, means *Perl Compatible Regular Expression* and is the default for `PHP`, `pcregrep` or with `grep -P`)

Relevant part of perl doc :

> (?:pattern)
> (?adluimsx-imsx:pattern)
> (?^aluimsx:pattern)
>
> This is for clustering, not capturing; it groups subexpressions like "()", but doesn't make backreferences as "()" does.

See this example using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ echo 'azfoobar' | perl -lne 'print $1 if /^(?:az)(.*)/'
foobar
```

As you can see, the first matching capturing group (`$1`) isn't `az` but the rest of the line. This works the same with the others languages like [python](/questions/tagged/python) or such.

Comment: Thanks. I just found a similar notation `(?i:...)` in `(?i:(?=[MDCLXVI])((M{0,3})((C[DM])|(D?C{0,3}))?((X[LC])|(L?XX{0,2})|L)?((I[VX])|(V?(II{0,2}))|V)?))`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JackWM, `(?i:...)` is a combination of the inline modifier `i` that turns on case independent matching and a non capturing group. Means: The pattern inside this group is not case sensitive and is not captured.

Comment: Added explanations and perl doc

Comment: PCRE is not a standard, it's the name of a library ([ref](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)).  There **is** no standard for regexes.  Case in point: the `(?^...)` construct is new in Perl v5.14.  I had never heard of it until now, and I would be extremely surprised if any other flavor has picked it up yet.

Answer (score 7):

`(?:...)` is just a non capturing group, means the part of the string that is matched by this group is not stored and can not be accessed by `$1` or `\1`

Capturing groups are numbered by the opening brackets, so

For the example text "Foobar test"

1. Here are two capturing groups

   ```
   ^(\w+)\s*(\w+)
    1       2
   ```

   This will result in:

   ```
   $1 = "Foobar"

   $2 = "test"
   ```
2. Here is only one capturing group:

   ```
   ^(?:\w+)\s*(\w+)
              1
   ```

   This will result in:

   ```
   $1 = "test"
   ```

Comment: @JackWM, an example of what? sidyll's link has a good explanation with example.

Comment: @JackWM, I added an example.

Answer (score 2):

`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, that is, it controls operator precedence but it won't create a match group.